# When Windows 2008 crashes, the complete memory dump is not written to disk

Tags: windows-server-2008, bsod

I have followed the instructions given here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969028 by the letter, but Windows doesn't seem to write a full memory dump.

I use NotMyFault.exe to blue screen the system to obtain the Complete Memory Dump, but nothing is written to disk. I've enabled page size to be greater than physical RAM (My machine has 6 GB of RAM), enabled PAE, etc. The crash dump is not present after the crash.

I need the full memory dump to provide to Microsoft

Comment: Are you running the 32-bit or 64-bit version of Windows 2008? How large is your page file exactly?

Comment: I'm running the 32 bit version. My page file is now set to initial size of 9GB and up to 12 GB.

Answer (score 3):

I had to make paging file 1.5 the size of physical RAM for **Complete memory dump** option to appear in **Startup and Recovery** settings.

I have 8 GB of RAM, and the size of my paging file is 12286 MB (12 GB). Before I made it, the complete memory dump wasn't created.

So in your case, the paging file needs to be 9 GB, or 9216 MB.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it, but still no luck. My page file is now 9 GB initial and 12 GB max. Still no luck after crashing and subsequently rebooting.

Comment: Is the option **Complete memory dump** available in the list? Try to select a different option, close the dialog, and then open it again to select **Complete memory dump**. Also check the system event log, there should be a record indicating why dump wasn't created. You can also try to increase the initial size of paging file a little bit more. And make sure there's enough free space to on the system drive. (In my case, after BSOD Windows displayed a dialog with error suggesting to send it to Microsoft, it deleted the dump file as soon as I dismissed the dialog.)

Comment: The option is available in the list. My App and System logs are absolutely clear - no errors anywhere. There's also 200 GB of drive space left. This is just absolutely baffling. A tech from MSFT has offered to take a look at the system. But thanks for your suggestions, it had helped me eliminate a lot of things that could potentially get in the way of a dump being written.

Comment: @KKP You're welcome. I spent quite a while until I managed to get the complete memory dump on my system. It's the only thing that helped to resolve the issue I had with an antivirus. They finally fixed it in the next version.